# Python: How to resolve a rounding error in a basic "chaos theory" program?

Tags: python, precision

I've learning Python from Zelle's Introduction to Python, and came across the following example for a basic program that simulates chaotic output based on an initial input.

```
 def main():
     print("This program illustrates a chaotic function")
     x = eval(input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: "))
     for i in range(10):
         x = 3.9 * x * (1 - x)
         print(x)

main()

This program illustrates a chaotic function

Enter a number between 0 and 1: .15
0.49724999999999997
0.97497050625
0.09517177095121285
0.3358450093643686
0.8699072422927216
0.4413576651876355
0.9615881986142427
0.14405170611022783
0.48087316710014555
0.9735732406265619
```

I'm aware that such rounding errors are inevitable with the default double-precision float data type in Python. For example, the first output value is exactly 0.49725. I read from somewhere that rounding errors could be resolved by using the Decimal function from Python's decimal library. So I modified the program slightly:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def main():
    print("This program illustrates a chaotic function")
    x = Decimal(eval(input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: ")))
    for i in range(10):
        x = Decimal(Decimal(3.9) * x * (Decimal(1) - x))
        print(x)

main()

This program illustrates a chaotic function

Enter a number between 0 and 1: .15
0.4972499999999999735211808627
0.9749705062499999772282405220
0.09517177095121305485295678083
0.3358450093643692781451067085
0.8699072422927223412528927684
0.4413576651876335014022344487
0.9615881986142417803060044330
0.1440517061102311988874201782
0.4808731671001548246798042829
0.9735732406265634386141115723
```

Is there any way to resolve this such that exact output values like 0.49725 are represented exactly? How are issues like this handled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from an intermediate step you're using: the `eval` call (which isn't the best way to parse user input into a float anyway - the `float` function is safer). This evaluates the user's input into whatever the Python interpreter would natively parse it as, which would be a float in this case. This means that when you do `Decimal(eval(input()))`, you've already interfered with the datum before passing it to `Decimal`, which merely works with what it's given. Remove the `eval` call and let `Decimal` itself handle the user's input. Additionally, you'll have to scrub every other native float, e.g. `Decimal(3.9)`, which creates a float out of 3.9 *first* before creating a `Decimal` out of it. You can avoid this by passing strings to `Decimal`.

```
>>> Decimal(Decimal(3.9) * Decimal(eval('.15')) * (Decimal(1) - Decimal(eval('.15'))))
Decimal('0.4972499999999999735211808627')
>>> Decimal(Decimal(3.9) * Decimal(.15) * (Decimal(1) - Decimal(.15)))
Decimal('0.4972499999999999735211808627')
>>> Decimal(Decimal(3.9) * Decimal('.15') * (Decimal(1) - Decimal('.15')))
Decimal('0.4972499999999999886757251488')
>>> Decimal(Decimal('3.9') * Decimal('.15') * (Decimal('1') - Decimal('.15')))
Decimal('0.49725')
```

Comment: A minor follow-up question - can this problem of compounding of floating point rounding errors be resolved by using the Numpy float64 or Numpy double as well? Bottom line: for stuff like financial calculations, it's clear to me that the default float type isn't the best to use. Can the datatypes decimal, np.float64 and np.double be safely used for such calculations?

Comment: @u23 - Those are all IEEE 754 binary floating-point numbers. Financial calculations use integers (representing e.g. pennies instead of dollars).